# Multiple TABLE JOIN.....SELECTING DATA FROM TABLE TO TABLE

Tags: php, mysql

I want to join table groups and groups2 from table users and selecting all user_id that is listed from table groups and table groups2. Here's my tables with its data:

[image: TABLE users]

[image: TABLE groups]

[image: TABLE groups2]

If you have noticed, table groups has user_id 1,1,1 and 4 while groups2 has user_id 1,1 and 3...

I'm using this code:

```
$query_groups = mysql_query("

SELECT users.user_id
FROM users

LEFT JOIN groups
ON groups.user_id=users.user_id

LEFT JOIN groups2
ON groups2.user_id=users.user_id

GROUP BY groups2.user_id

");
 while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_groups))
{
          echo $rows['user_id']."<br />";

}
```

But what I get is the result of: `2 1 and 3` instead of what I want to get which is `1 4 and 3`

Comment: group by `users.user_id`?

Comment: Feels like you are going about this the worng way. Why not have a table with groups: UserID, GroupID

Comment: @JelleFerwerda, if I'm not mistaken, your point sir is I must have table groups with UserId that is not the same with users: user_id, Is it really matter?

Comment: Once you have a table called groups, and a table called groups2 you most likely are making life needlessly complex. Assuming both tables have the same colums, keeping just one table groups, with a coloum identifying the group a specific user belongs to, makes more sense. That way you can expand to 3, 10 or 1000 groups without having to modify your database coding.

Comment: @adamS, Yes sir? I'm still skeptical on that part to...

Comment: @adamS, I get 1,2,3 and 4....which user_id '2' is not included on the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

```
SELECT distinct uid from 
(SELECT distinct user_id uid from groups
UNION
SELECT distinct user_id uid from groups2) gps
```

If you just need user_id you don't need the user table.

Else you can get user info by join user after this query :

```
SELECT distinct gps.uid, u.first_name from 
    (SELECT distinct user_id uid from groups
    UNION
    SELECT distinct user_id uid from groups2) gps,
    users u
WHERE u.user_id = gps.uid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) user_id FROM groups 
UNION SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) user_id FROM groups2) user_id ;
```

result:

```
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
|       1 |
|       4 |
|       3 |
+---------+
```

UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 0):

if you need to get users from users tables that have links on groups table only, you may use inner join. Inner join get data from tables if linked objects exists in both tables only.
Example:

```
SELECT distinct(users.user_id)
FROM users

INNER JOIN groups
ON groups.user_id=users.user_id

INNER JOIN groups2
ON groups2.user_id=users.user_id

GROUP BY groups2.user_id
```

And if you need to get all user data from users table - you need to specify grouping rule for each users table field. Like distinct(users.user_id)
You can read more about join types here [Join types](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)